# Autenticação de proxy no Cinnamon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy

Estou configurando uma máquina Linux Ubuntu com interface gŕafica com cinnamon 3, porém não estão conseguindo fazer o Google Chrome abrir uma janela de autenticação de proxy, sei que o Google Chrome usa um sistema de autenticação do proxy diferente do Firefox (que pode ser setado diretamente na config do navegador) pois puxa o proxy do S.O.

Estou usando um proxy.pac (também tentei pelo endereço e porta) com as configurações do meu proxy, quando adiciono o arquivo no proxy do sistema, o chrome reconhece o arquivo mas não abre janela de autenticação.

Cheguei a configurar no apt.conf, também no /etc/profile. 
Cheguei também a setar no atalho o comando --proxy-server="IP proxy Server:port" mas sem sucesso.

O estranho é que no KDE ele funciona tanto com o .pac quanto com server:porta, no gnome ele funciona apenas com o server:porta (ambos configurados nas opções de proxy do sistema) mas no cinnamon não funciona com nenhum dos dois modos.

No Chromium eu vi que tem gente que conseguiu utilizar. Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu contornar o problema?

Obrigado.

Comment: a flag `--proxy-server` tem que funcionar, pois segundo a documentação ela atropela todas as outras fontes de configuração de proxy pro Chromium. Que tipo de proxy vc usa? Ele pede autenticação com login e senha? Se sim, pode usar o PAC (proxy login automator), ou um servidor http como proxy reverso, ou ainda o Cntlm pra autenticar no seu proxy e abrir uma porta local para usar na configuração do browser.